# Creating Relationship in neo4j using neo4j-nodejs API

Tags: javascript, node.js, neo4j, nodes, graph-databases

i am creating relationship between two nodes that are created within the code but got error, can sombody tell me what should be arguments of fucnction below and what should be its format

```
node1.createRelationshipTo(node2, "some", {age:"20"}, function(err, relationship1)
{
if (err) {
    console.err('Error saving new node to database:', err);
         }
else {
    relationship1.save(function (err,result)
       {
if(err)
           {
console.err('Error saving new node to database:', err);
           } 
        });
     }
});
```

Comment: '...but got error' is NOT helpful.

Answer (score 0):

No need to save the relationship after creating it.  You can use relationship1 within the callback function.

```
node1.createRelationshipTo(node2, "some", {age:"20"}, function(err, relationship1) {
  if (err) {
    console.err('Error saving new node to database:', err);
  } else {
    // Do something with relationship1 here.
});
```